# How to get count from first table field when joining

Tags: mysql, join

I have two mysql tables in database. table1 and table2.

Table1

```
event_id  |  event_name
------------------------
1         |  event1
------------------------
2         |  event2
------------------------
3         |  event3
------------------------
```

Table2

```
time_id  |  event_id  |  time_name  |  status  |
-----------------------------------------------
1        |  1         |   morning   |  paid    |
------------------------------------------------
2        |  1         |   morning   |  not paid |
------------------------------------------------
3        |  2         |   afternoon |  paid     |
-------------------------------------------------
```

I want to get count of `event_id` from first table after joining these two table based on `event_id`. Why I need to join is because, I need to have a WHERE condition in time_name.

So far my query is like this,

```
SELECT count(`table1`.`event_id`) FROM `table1` JOIN `table2` ON `table2`.`event_id` = `table1`.`event_id` WHERE `table2`.`time_name` = 'morning'
```

But I get result as 2. Why it is so? My required result is 1

Comment: How do you need to use `time_id` in the `WHERE`?

Comment: Why `2`? `table2` has two rows with `event_id = 1`.

Comment: Sorry @ajmedway : It was a mistake. I need to use time_name in where condition

Comment: @Praveen : Yes. Table2 will have multiple values for table1. That is the requirement

Comment: @Corner please check my answer and upvote/accept if it works for you, thanks!

Comment: @Corner just updated my answer as per the change in code in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing an INNER JOIN on table 2 using the event_id field (which only gets rows where table2 has an event_id) so you need to do use a LEFT JOIN, which will return all of rows from table1 (except those excluded in the `WHERE`) and joins on any rows from table2 with a matching event_id (otherwise returning NULL fields in their place):

```
SELECT count(`table1`.`event_id`) AS t1_event_count
FROM `table1`
LEFT JOIN `table2` ON `table2`.`event_id` = `table1`.`event_id`
WHERE `table2`.`time_name` = 'morning'
```

Comment: Thank you so much @ajmedway